# Use php array outside his function

Tags: php, array

any ideas why my function print_r $arr with lot of elements, 
but only retain cat and dog when it comes to print_r $stack?
I need to have $arr used outside the function,

```
function pre_selected_results() {
    $args = array(...)
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $arr = array("Dog","Cat");

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        $the_query->the_post();
        $args = array(...)
        $results = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(),'type',$args);  
        foreach ($results as $result){
            $arr[] = $result;   
        } 
    endwhile;
    print_r ($arr);
    return $arr;
};//End of pre_get_results function
$stack = pre_selected_results();
print_r ($stack);
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT :  my $args in case that helps: for the quey :

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(
'relation' => 'OR',
 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'terms' => $_GET['category'],
    'field' => 'slug',
),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'genres',
    'terms' => $_GET['genre'],
    'field' => 'slug',
),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'types',
    'terms' => $_GET['type'],
    'field' => 'slug',
),
```

);

and for the wp_get_post_term:

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'slugs');
```

thanks again

Comment: Looks like because your query has no posts, or posts have no taxonomies assigned. What arguments do you pass to `WP_Query` and `wp_get_post_terms`?

Comment: No , my query displays lot of posts,using 3 differents taxonomies,and then print_r arr with all the result, but $stack refuse to have those as well...^^

Comment: If `print_r ($arr);` at the end of the function shows something else then `print_r ($stack);` it is probably related to PHP syntax and parameter passing and not to WP

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
array_merge( $arr, $results );
```

Instead of:

```
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $arr[] = $result;   
}
```

Comment: Would have posted as comment except for code formatting